# app crashed every time i run it

Tags: android, admob

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">   

     <TextView 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

     <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/ad"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="***************"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

SimpleBanerAd Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.simplebanerad"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="13"
         android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
             android:name="com.example.simplebanerad.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity 
             android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"                 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
         </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

MainActivity.java package com.example.simplebanerad;

```
 import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
 android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity { @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }


     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
     } }
```

I want to display ads but my app crashes everytime I run it. I run it on 4.2.2 API level 17 emulator. where I am going wrong?

Comment: What does the crash in the log say?

Comment: in console it says : [2013-04-01 12:10:54 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Comment: That's not the one I meant.  If you crashed, a full stack trace of where you crashed should be in there.  That's what we need.

Comment: Your question should display apt amount of research and effort before you post it right away. Please get a hang of eclipse and android in general before posting here.

Comment: LocGate:04-01 06:44:07.329: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 06:44:07.329: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplebanerad/com.example.simplebanerad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.admob.android.ads.AdView
04-01 06:44:07.329: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-01 06:44:07.329: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

Answer (score 0):

> Error inflating class com.admob.android.ads.AdView

You are getting this error, because the AdView class is not in the `com.admob.android.ads` package, it's in the `com.google.ads` package.

So change this:

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/ad"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="***************"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```

To this:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/ad"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="***************"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```

Comment: Edit your question and add your LogCat to it.

Comment: 04-01 07:46:04.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 07:46:04.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplebanerad/com.example.simplebanerad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView